# libvlc api calls failing without Sleep

Tags: visual-c++, libvlc

I am working on integrating Media Player into my MFC dialog box.The dialog box is created from a dll which wraps libvlc.My problem is after I set the output window to a static control in dialog and play the media it works fine.But other API calls like getting length and getting time fails if I call it from my methods.But as soon as I introduce a Sleep(100),everything seems to work.I am wondering what could be the issue.What i want to do is play video between user provided timeline(i.e. if user want only 5 minutes of video out of 15 minutes length between time A to time B).

The sleep seems to work fine but there is always an unwanted delay in playback that I do not want.Please if somebody can give pointers on how to achieve this.

Comment: You are trying to get length after starting the media?

Comment: Yes after playing the media file...the video plays fine but if I call libvlc APIs through a thread it fails without sleep.

Comment: Please share an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @mtz sure I will..please wait for some time because its not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Sleep works if I have worker threads running in my application.But if I handle the working through the libVLC event handler it works fine without Sleep.Seems like I am missing a very fundamental logic here but since this works for now,I will go with this. Thank you all.